# detecting spaces in curly brace in php

Tags: php, regex

I have to convert tokens from an old system that uses { and }, since these are a very bad token, i want to use something different (i want to use something like: |token|)

all tokens are like this:

- TOKEN1
- TOKEN_1
- 1TOKEN

i have some php pages that has css and token inside and I dont want to replace css for example:

```
$html = '... 
body { font-size: 12px; }
...
{TOKEN1}
...
{token2}
';
```

I want to be able to change only the tokens and leave the css as is.

i have this:

```
$p = '/{([^}]*)}/';
  $t = preg_match_all($p, $html, $matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

but still does not remove the css. i get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => { font-size: 12px; }
                    [1] => 10
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => {TOKEN1}
                    [1] => 35
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => {token2}
                    [1] => 48
                )

        )
```

Do i have to do another loop to figure out which one i have to ignore? or there's a magical regex that will fix it?

Comment: are your tokens only ever a single word? If so, then just mod your regex to exclude any `{}` pairs that contain spaces or other separators.

Comment: again... are those tokens ever something like `{token1=foo}` or `{token2 123}`? or are they only ever a SINGLE word, `{token1}`?

Comment: nothing like that, they are all like {token1}, i do not have anything between them including space, it's only letters, numbers or _ only

Comment: then have your regex exclude any `{}` matches which contain non-letter/non-number stuff. css cannot possibly ever havea  `{font}`-type rule, so if you exclude `:`, `[space]` and the like, css rules will never match for your tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$p = '/{([^}{ :]*)}/';
```

It will only match curly brackets that do not have other curly brackets, space or : in it.

Comment: You may also want to exclude `;`, try this one: `$p = '/{([^}{ :;]*)}/';`